# Can Havdalah spices be eaten afterwards?

Tags: halacha, eating, havdalah, spices

Can someone partake of the havdalah spices for "secular" purposes (i.e. eating, etc.) after the service is concluded?

I know that one should not intentionally 'smell' his esrog on Sukkos (machlokes). Can one eat of the spices after being used for havdalah? Furthermore, if one did eat of them, could he use the remainder for the next havdalah?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, yes and yes

The to use the spices for havdolo is not a mitzvah as long as you have pleasure from there smell you can use them

[Shulchan aruch harav 297.1](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh2/1/297/1.htm)

> הנהיגו חכמים להריח **בבשמים בכל מוצאי שבת** כדי להשיב את הנפש שהיא דואבת ליציאת השבת בשביל הנשמה יתירה שהלכה לפיכך מיישבים ומשמחין אותה בריח טוב במה דברים אמורים כשיש לו בשמים אזי הוא צריך להריח בהם אבל אם אין לו **אין צריך לחזר אחריהם כדרך שמחזרים אחר המצות הואיל ואינם אלא בשביל להשיב את הנפש**

Shulchan aruch

הלכות לולב-סימן תרנג - הדס אסור להריח בו, ובו ב' סעיפים

א.

> הדס של מצוה אסור להריח בו **אבל אתרוג של מצוה מותר להריח בו מן הדין אלא שלפי שנחלקו אם מברכים עליו אם לאו יש לא יש למנוע מלהריח בו:**

Harav in his sidur 
 [פסקי הסידור > סדר ברכת הנהנין > פרק יא](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/piskey/52/11.htm)

(ח)

> אין מברכין על הריח הטוב אלא אם כן נעשה להריח בו אבל מוגמר שמגמרים בו את הבגדים ליתן בהם ריח אין מברכין עליו לפי שלא נעשה להריח בעצמו של מוגמר ואין צריך לומר מוגמר שמגמרין בבית להעביר ממנו ריח רע ואפילו בשמים שמוליך עמו האסטניס לבית הכסא לבטל הריח רע אין מברכין עליהם כלל אף אם בא להריח בהם שלא בבית הכסא הואיל ואין עומדים להריח בהם ליהנות מריחם רק להעביר ריח רע בלבד. ולכן יש אומרים שהמריח **באתרוג** של מצוה אין מברך עליו כל שבעת ימי החג. אף על פי שמותר להריח בו אינו עומד להריח בו אלא ליטלו לשם מצוה ואינו דומה **לאתרוג** של כל השנה ושאר פירות העומדים לאכילה שאף על פי שעיקרם לאכילה מכל מקום רגילות הוא ג"כ להריח מהם בשעת אכילה ולכך נקראים ג"כ עומדים לריח. ויש אומרים שגם בשבעת ימי החג מאחר שמותר להריח בו נקרא ג"כ עומד לריח כמו בשאר ימות השנה ולכן טוב למנוע מלהריח בו כל החג להנצל מספק ברכה. אבל ההדס מן הדין אסור להריח בו כל החג כמ"ש בהלכות לולב

Comment: If you want translation of sources please ask